# In react, how to clone GLTF/glb objects?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, react-hooks, three.js, clone

Basically, I am developing a react app with react-three/fiber. I got a .glb file in public folder. In one component named "ShowLK.js" I use useGLTF as shown below. The problem is that I can only display ONE object in my Boxes Component (at any place on the app) when I want to be able to display the same object at least 20 times.

I got this:

```
import { useGLTF } from "@react-three/drei";

function ShowLK({x, y, z}) {
  const { scene } = useGLTF("LKGLB.glb");
  return <primitive object={scene} position={[x, y, z]} scale={[0.57, 0.57, 0.57]} />;
}

export default ShowLK;
```

Then I got other Component element where I try to display it:

```
import React from 'react'
import ShowLK from "./ShowLK";


const Boxes = () => {
  return (
<>
    <ShowLK 
    x={9}
    y={0}
    z={81}
      />
    <ShowLK 
    x={-9}
    y={0}
    z={81}
      />

</>
  )
}

export default Boxes
```

I tried searching for an afternoon trying to grasp the problem and find solution but didnt really solve it. I guess I need ID on each object when it clones?

I find gltfjsx but it said Requirements: Nodejs must be installed. Which I dont use.

Comment: Just `.clone()` whatever object you want to duplicate: https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/core/Object3D.clone

Comment: How can it be applied in this specific example please?

Comment: So i used chatGTP...   const duplicatedScene = scene.clone(); and   return <primitive object={duplicatedScene} position={[x, y, z]} scale={[0.57, 0.57, 0.57]} />;

Answer (score 3):

You can use a Clone component from @react-three/drei.

```
import { Clone, useGLTF } from '@react-three/drei';

export const Model = () => {
  const model = useGLTF('LKGLB.glb');

  return (
    <>
      <Clone object={model.scene} scale={0.35} position-x={-4} />
      <Clone object={model.scene} scale={0.35} position-x={0} />
      <Clone object={model.scene} scale={0.35} position-x={4} />
    </>
  );
}
```

Comment: how to do this when you want to use nodes not the scene?