# Clone the nodes from a GLB file loaded with useGLTF in react three fiber?

Tags: reactjs, three.js, react-three-fiber, react-three-drei

I am loading my model with useGLTF like this, and access to its nodes, since I need to manipulate them:

```
  const { nodes, materials } = useGLTF("/model.glb");

    <group>
        <primitive object={nodes.RootNode} />

        <skinnedMesh
            // @ts-ignore
            geometry={nodes.outfit1.geometry}
            // @ts-ignore
            material={nodes.outfit4.material}
            // @ts-ignore
            skeleton={nodes.outfit4.skeleton}
        />
        <skinnedMesh
            // @ts-ignore
            geometry={nodes.haircut.geometry}
            // @ts-ignore
            material={nodes.haircut.material}
            // @ts-ignore
            skeleton={nodes.haircut.skeleton}
        />
    </group>
```

Now I want to reuse the component but I know you have to clone the model to have it multiple times in your scene in react three fiber; as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74815772/in-react-how-to-clone-gltf-glb-objects) you could use the Clone component from drei, but .clone only works on scene. How can I handle this?

```
import { Clone, useGLTF } from '@react-three/drei';
export const Model = () => {
  const model = useGLTF('LKGLB.glb');
  return (
    <>
      <Clone object={model.scene} scale={0.35} position-x={-4} />
      <Clone object={model.scene} scale={0.35} position-x={0} />
      <Clone object={model.scene} scale={0.35} position-x={4} />
    </>
  );
}
```

or use .clone() on the scene:

```
 const { scene } = useLoader(GLTFLoader, url)
  const copiedScene = useMemo(() => scene.clone(), [scene])

  return (
    <group>
      <primitive object={copiedScene} position={position} />
    </group>
  );
```

how to do this when I want to use nodes?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`useGraph`](https://docs.pmnd.rs/react-three-fiber/api/hooks#usegraph) from react-three-fiber to get the nodes. For skinned meshes you can use the clone function of Three's [SkeletonUtils](https://threejs.org/docs/index.html?q=skeleton#examples/en/utils/SkeletonUtils).

```
import { SkeletonUtils } from "three-stdlib"
import { useGraph } from '@react-three/fiber'

const scene = useLoader(OBJLoader, url)
const clone = useMemo(() => SkeletonUtils.clone(scene), [scene])
const { nodes } = useGraph(clone)
```

[Here is an example](https://codesandbox.io/s/k8phr?file=/src/Model.js) from the react-three-fiber documentation where this is used.

You can also use `useGLTF` to get the scene:

```
const { scene } = useGLTF(url)
```